# phpSeclib real time output using PHP?

Tags: php, shell, phpseclib

I am trying to get the output of a ping command using phpSeclib. I tried the examples on their official website but none of them work, they all just execute the command and display the output once done.

Is it possible to directly show the output everytime the shell changes? So everytime a new ping is done show it to the user.

It works perfectly in CLI mode, but not in the browser.

I am looking for a fully PHP solution. No AJAX or jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#callback :

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

function packet_handler($str)
{
    echo $str;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', 'packet_handler');
?>
```

You may want to play around with `flush()` and `ob_flush()` as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I already saw that snippet. However what is the best way to implement the flush?

Comment: http://php.net/flush it's a built-in function. And it doesn't work on every server. I mean, the function should be callable on every server but it may not behave in the same way on every server.

Comment: Okay, do you have a code snippet for me? I assume the flush() function should be called several times until the command is finished?

Comment: Thanks again for your help neubert. The code works with simple commands like LS and MKDIR. But commands like ping aren't working, and the code is waiting until the command is done, then the output is shown. So it's not realtime...

Comment: A lot of that could be that the server you're using just doesn't support flush / ob_flush being used in the way you're wanting to use them. I tried phpseclib on the CLI and it did what you were trying to do without flush / ob_flush. Maybe you could try it on the CLI as well. You could also try `for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) { echo 'X'; flush(); ob_flush(); sleep(1); }` to see if that's the problem and not phpseclib as I suspect.